# Xcode -> Profile -> Instruments 'Can't find source code for selected symbol'

Tags: xcode, instruments

I'm attempting to use Xcode & Instruments to Time Profile my app - but there's something in my environment which is preventing Instruments from linking back to source code.  It's this way with all of my apps, and even with a recent tutorial from Kodeco (RayWenderlich.com) - so I'm suspecting my environment.

In Xcode, I select Product -> Profile, which launches Instruments.  I select Time Profiler.  I click the record button, use the app such that the area of interest is executed, hit stop.

In the Profile section of Instruments, I can see the stack traces, and many of them have function names which are clearly from my app.

When I double-click on them, I expect them to show the source code from Xcode (as detailed in apple docs and the Kodeco tutorial).

However, instead I get this screen which says "Error: Can't find source code for selected symbol"

[image: error: can't find source]

Most of the stack overflow question / answers I've seen come from many years ago, which suggests that my problem isn't common - which has me wondering what I've got lurking in my environment that's preventing this from working.

I'm using an M1 Mac w/ Ventura 13.1 Beta (22C5044e) and Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b).

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Still non-functional in Ventura 13.1 Beta (22C5050e)

Comment: I wish I had a solution, but I just have the same problem also. I tried deleting DerivedData, rebooting, but same problem still.

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason was that dSYM file was not generated for Debug builds => Instruments could not symbolicate the build.

You can change the setting in Xcode -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Debug Information Format.

[image]